# Link A .mobileconfig To A UDID

Tags: ios, configuration, udid, ipcu

How can i link a .mobileconfig file created with iPCU.
I need it for a app signing service but to be linked to a single UDID if posible, else if anyone knows if a can do some serverside stuff. 
Thanks here is the .mobileconfig file: https://hastebin.com/oyulawesay.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by linking created mobile config file with device UDID but there are few ways to have unique mobile config for each device:

1. You can send your UDID (`[NSUUID UUID]`) as a request parameter to the server - generate mobile config file on the server side with script (python is recommended here) and return it to the user. Here's example of lib that does it:

   https://github.com/scj643/iOS-Profile-Lib.
2. Redirect user to safari and use this solution:

   http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/getting-an-iphone-udid-from-mobile-safari/.
3. You can generate/modify a pattern of this profile in your application without using server. Then use GCDServer and run Safari linking your profile available via GCDServer.